How to fix first time intallation, Docker hello-world permission denied: unknown
I installed Docker Engine step by step from documentation. But getting this error when I try to run hello-world. I'm trying this on a Ubuntu 24.04 server.
root@slimme-rik:/var/lib/docker# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "proc" to rootfs at "/proc": mount src=proc, dst=/proc, dstFd=/proc/thread-self/fd/8, flags=0xe: permission denied: unknown.

I disabled apparmor. And don't have any firewall running currently. But it's saying permission denied. I cannot change the permissions for /proc.

You can either
a. Add your user to docker user group (recommended)
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

restart terminal (or reconnect SSH), then run the command
docker run hello-world

b. Use sudo for running docker
sudo docker run hello-world

Explanation

The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket, not a TCP port. By default it's the root user that owns the Unix socket, and other users can only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user.


If you don't want to preface the docker command with sudo, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker group. On some Linux distributions, the system automatically creates this group when installing Docker Engine using a package manager. In that case, there is no need for you to manually create the group.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
